# Pushing JMeter code to GIT repository: Error with 'src refspec' and 'failed to push some refs'

Tags: git, azure-devops

After entering the cmd as **git push -u origin** getting error as :-src refspec doesn't match and failed to push some refs to link. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea2t7.png)

so entered cmd as **git push --set-upstream origin master** got error as: Blocked by internet explorer enhanced security configuration.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Qe7.png)

Could anyone please help me. Also softwares installed in vm are:

**1.Git Bash.2. intellij IDE**.

So could anyone suggest the possible ways to push the code to **AZURE GIT Repository**

As part of **JMETER(SELENIUM SCRIPTS) Integration With Azure Pipeline**

Comment: Notice that you are on branch `master` trying to push `main`. Does `main` exist locally? (side note: please, replace the image for the console text in the question).